# R Studio gzfile error when using library() function

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting an error when trying to utilize any installed packages.

Here is the code I use.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
> library(tidyverse)
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/M/Appdata/Local/R/win-library/4.2/vctrs/R/vctrs.rdx', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 unable to load R code in package ‘vctrs’
```

I have tried the following:

- restarting R Studio
- re-installing R Studio
- downloading the packages and putting them in wd()
- tried moving the wd()

appreciate the help

Comment: What does `install.packages("vctrs")` give?

Comment: here is what i get:
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk9PXIf\downloaded_packages
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state